# mysqlのerror logを開くと、「ファイルを読み込めません」と表示される

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

タイトル通りですが、mysqlのコントロールパネルからlogを見ようと、

Open logのボタンを押すと、ファイルを読み込めませんという表示がされerror logが見れません。

どうして、このような表示になるのでしょうか。

セキュリティ上の理由でmysqlがファイルをブロックしているのでしょうか。

ネットで検索しても今ひとつ手がかりを掴むことが出来ませんでした。

お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 画面に表示されているのは`*.local.pid`で、明らかに`error.log`とは違うファイルですよね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAMPPでは確かMysqlのログ出力設定が初期状態でされてなかった気がします。
設定ファイルにログ出力設定がされているか確認してください。

もし設定が無ければ、出力されていないから読み込めないだけだと思います。